# Decomposition of a stochastic process into a continuous and pure jump part

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

We work on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in [0,T]},P)$. Let $X$ be an adapted làdlàg stochastic process (i.e. the left and right limits exist). For $0<t<T$ denote by $\Delta_+ X_t := X_{t+}-X_t$ its right and by $\Delta X_t := X_t -X_{t-}$ its left jumps.

In [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/43860072.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A0843787f6b0ae279f79832fcbcdbbe0c) paper on page 1894 it is claimed that the continuous part of $X$ is given by
\begin{equation}
X_t^c:=X_t -\sum_{s<t}\Delta_+ X_s -\sum_{s\leq t}\Delta X_s.
\end{equation}
However, since $\sum_{s<\cdot}\Delta_+ X_s$ is right-continuous, shouldn't we take the left limit of this sum, i.e.
\begin{equation}
X_t^c:=X_t -\left(\sum_{s<t}\Delta_+ X_s\right)_- -\sum_{s\leq t}\Delta X_s
\end{equation}
so that $X^c$ is continuous?

Comment: The sum $\sum_{s<\cdot} \Delta_+X_s$ is left continuous.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you. The fact that the sum $\sum_{s<\cdot}\Delta_+ X_s$ is left-continuous explains that both formulations in my question are actually correct. Do you have a reference for a proof of the left-continuity?

Comment: @hannah better than a reference is trying to prove it ourselves. See my edit of the answer.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I have a follow-up question (that is related to my original question): Assume additionally that $X$ is predictable and let $Y$ be a càdlàg process. Consider the process $A:=\sum_{s<\cdot} Y_s \Delta_+ X_s$. Is $A$ predictable? Intuitively, the answer should be yes, because $A_t$ only includes terms strictly before $t$. However, I do not know how to argue this formally.

Comment: Yes: $A$ is adapted and left continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example
$$\tag{1}
X_t=a1_{\{0\}}(t)+1_{(0,+\infty)}(t)
$$
of a làdlàg path should show what $X_t^c$ should be. Obviously,
\begin{align}
X_{t-}&=1_{(0,+\infty)}(t), \\[3mm]
X_{t+}&=1_{[0,+\infty)}(t),\\[3mm]
\Delta_+X_t&=X_{t+}-X_t=(1-a)1_{\{0\}}(t),\\[3mm]
\Delta_-X_t&=X_t-X_{t-}=a1_{\{0\}}(t)\,.
\end{align}
Further, considering when the single jump occurs it is easy to see that
\begin{align}
\sum_{s<t}\Delta_+X_s&=(1-a)1_{(0,+\infty)}(t)\,,\tag{2}\\
\sum_{s\le t}\Delta_-X_s&=a1_{[0,+\infty)}(t)\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
As ***commented by John Dawkins***, (2) is left continuous. Now we see that
\begin{align}
X^c_t&=X_t-(1-a)1_{(0,+\infty)}(t)-a1_{[0,+\infty)}(t)\\
&=\Big(a1_{\{0\}}+1_{(0,+\infty)}-(1-a)1_{(0,+\infty)}-a1_{[0,+\infty)}\Big)(t)\\
&\equiv0\,
\end{align}
which is continuous.

The proof that (2) is always left continuous goes as follows: Let $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence with $t_n<t\,,t_n\uparrow t\,.$ Clearly,

$$
\bigcup_{\scriptstyle t_n<t\atop\scriptstyle t_n\uparrow t}(-\infty,t_n)=(-\infty,t)\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{s<t_n}\Delta_+X_s\quad\to\quad \sum_{s<t}\Delta_+X_s
$$
because every $s<t$ is in all intervals $(-\infty,t_n)$ provided that $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Thank you for the proof. One comment: The notation "$\uparrow$" suggests that the sequence on the left is increasing. However, I don't think this is true in general for $\sum_{s<t_n}\Delta_+ X_s$ ($X$ can have negative right jumps).

Comment: @hannah indeed ! Thanks for pointing that out.